# Typecasting to a bit-field

Tags: c, gcc, casting

I am trying to assign a value to a bit field in a struct. It is a demotion since the assigned variable is of a smaller size than the type used on the right hand side. Is there a way to force typecast it, understanding that there is some risk in demotion. This is test code, and I do not expect the right hand value to ever be greater than what my bit field can take.

Compiling using:

```
    gcc -Wconversion compileError.c
```

Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef unsigned long  int uint64_t;
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint64_t  val:48;
    uint16_t  length;
}data_t;

static data_t testData[10] = {};

int main()
{
    data_t*   pData = (data_t*)&testData;
    uint64_t  var   = 0;

    pData->val = var + 1;

    printf("Just trying to compile this program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Output:

```
compileError.c: In function main:
compileError.c:19:22: warning: conversion to long unsigned   
int:48 from uint64_t may alter its value [-Wconversion]
 pData->val = var + 1;
```

Comment: What happens when you try `typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;`?

Comment: Same output as before. sizeof(uint64_t) returns 8 for my test code.

Comment: Well, until I made that change from `unsigned long` MSVC reported "error C2034: 'val' : type of bit field too small for number of bits". After the change, a clean compilation (apart from the empty `{}` initialiser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174307) shows how you can temporarily silence that warning.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
    pData->val = var + 1;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

There's an open GCC Enhancement Request to address this, and there's a [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39170#c9) showing a workaround using masking.

```
pData-> val = (var + 1) & 0xffffffffffffLU
```